# Function is undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-props, mern

I have a function named `Addphoto` and I am passing that by props but I am getting an error that `Addphoto` is not a function

this is my main.js where i created routes

```
   <div>
        <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<><Title todo={'PhotoFrame'} /> <PhotoFrame PhotoBlock={this.state.allPhotos} onRemovePhoto={this.removePhoto} /></>}/>
          <Route path="/AddPhoto" element={<AddPhoto onAddPhoto={(addedPhoto)=>{
            console.log(addedPhoto)
          }}/>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
```

here is the code of addphoto.js where i creatd ny function

```
class AddPhoto extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.handlesSubmit = this.handlesSubmit.bind(this)
    }
    handlesSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const imageLink = event.target.elements.link.value
        const description = event.target.elements.description.value
        const photo = {
            id: 0,
            description:description,
            imageLink:imageLink
        }
        console.log(photo)
        if(description&&imageLink){
            // this.props.onAddphoto(photo)
            this.props.AddPhoto()
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
          <div>
              <h1>photo frame</h1>
              <div className='form'>
                  <form onSubmit={this.handlesSubmit}>
                     <input type="text" placeholder='Link' name='link'/>
                     <input type="text" placeholder='Description' name='description'/>
                     <button>Submit</button>
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

here is the error is occuring in my console

[image]

Comment: `<AddPhoto onAddPhoto={` — Your prop is called `onAddPhoto`.

Answer (score 0):

So, you gave a different name to the prop -onAddPhoto.
If you want to have access to addPhoto function inside AddPhoto.js:

```
const addPhoto = () => {
   // functionality to add a photo
}

<Route path="/AddPhoto" element={<AddPhoto addPhoto={addPhoto}/>
```

Now you can call this.props.addPhoto() inside AddPhoto component.